# Merge different duplicated row based on one column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table such as :

```
Chrs    pos value
Chr1    1   9
Chr1    2   11
Chr1    3   13
Chr1    4   13
Chr1    5   13
Chr1    6   13
Chr1    7   14
Chr1    8   14
Chr1    9   14
```

Does someone have an idea using pandas to transform it as :

```
Chrs    start end  value
Chr1    1     2    9
Chr1    2     3    11
Chr1    3     6    13
Chr1    7     9    14
```

As you can see, I added two columns `'start'` and `'end'` and I merged the same values into the same row by adding the last value into the end column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cond1 = df.groupby(df['value'])['value'].count().eq(1)

(df
 .groupby(df['value']).agg({'Chrs':'first', 'pos':['first', 'last'], 'value':'first'})
 .set_axis(['Chrs', 'first', 'last', 'value'], axis=1)
 .assign(last=lambda x: x['last'].mask(cond1, x['first'].shift(-1)))
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output:

```
    Chrs    first   last    value
0   Chr1    1       2       9 
1   Chr1    2       3       11
2   Chr1    3       6       13
3   Chr1    7       9       14
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with consecutive values in `value` column and aggregate
[`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)/
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or [`GroupBy.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html)/ [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), last set next value per `Chrs` if equal `start` and `end` values:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Chrs', df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()])
        .agg(start=('pos','first'),end=('pos','last'),value=('value','first')))


df.loc[df['end'].eq(df['start']),'end'] = df.groupby('Chrs')['start'].shift(-1)

df = df.droplevel(1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Chrs  start  end  value
0  Chr1      1  2.0      9
1  Chr1      2  3.0     11
2  Chr1      3  6.0     13
3  Chr1      7  9.0     14
```

If always counter `pos` values and need add `1` if same values in `start` and `end`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Chrs', df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()])
        .agg(start=('pos','first'),end=('pos','last'),value=('value','first')))


df.loc[df['end'].eq(df['start']),'end'] += 1

df = df.droplevel(1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Chrs  start  end  value
0  Chr1      1    2      9
1  Chr1      2    3     11
2  Chr1      3    6     13
3  Chr1      7    9     14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) after making a custom grouper for consecutive values on `pos`:

```
(df.sort_values(by=['Chrs', 'pos', 'value'])
   .groupby(['Chrs', df['pos'].diff().gt(1).cumsum(), 'value'], as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'start': ('pos', 'min'),
           'end': ('pos', lambda x: x.max() if len(x)>1 else x.max()+1)
          })
)
```

Output:

```
   Chrs  value  start  end
0  Chr1      9      1    2
1  Chr1     11      2    3
2  Chr1     13      3    6
3  Chr1     14      7    9
```